# Space between equal points circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[european, scale=1]
        \draw
            (0,0) node[ocirc]{} --
            ++(right:1) node(point1){} to [R, l=$R$]
            ++(down:2) node(point2){} --
            ++(left:1) node[ocirc]{}
            (node cs:name=point1) node[circ]{} --
            ++(right:2) to [C, l=$C$]
            ++(down:2) --
            (node cs:name=point2) node[circ]{}
        ;
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Why is there space between `point1` (definition) and `point1` (usage)?

[image: outputOfCode]

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really know. Something to do with the shape's anchor, but I'd have to refresh my TikZ to fix this. Not today :)
In the meantime, if you use (point1.center) instead of just (point1) it works.

Comment: @kenshin Does it have to do with `inner sep` and/or `outer sep` at all? Normally TiKZ puts space around nodes but I don't know `circuitikz` at all so perhaps that's not it. Why `(node cs:name=point1)` rather than `(point1)` anyway?

Comment: @kenshin: (point1.center) works fine. Thanks.

Comment: @cfr: I didn't know that only (point1) is equal but it is really equal. This means that space is also there.

Comment: @MichaelBanucu Yes. The space problem is there. I just wondered why you used what seemed to be a roundabout way of referring to `(point1)`. (Since it seemed equivalent when I tested but I don't know the package at all so I thought maybe it would cause problems in more complex cases.)

Comment: @cfr Probably something like that, yes. I'll check it for the next release :)

Comment: Alternative: Use [`pst-circ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-circ); it is easy to use and the macros for drawing electrical circuits have very intuitive names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't want to leave this question unanswered.

In addition to the comment suggesting `point1.center` and `point2.center` will work. My study also finds another two alternatives to close the gap, thus posting as an answer.

1. Said in the comment above.

New findings

2. Use explicit coordinate.
3. Change `node` definition into `coordinate` definition.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[european, scale=1]
        \draw
            (0,0) node[ocirc]{} --
            ++(right:1) node(point1){} to [R, l=$R$]
            ++(down:2)  node(point2){} --
            ++(left:1) node[ocirc]{}
            (point1.center) node[circ]{} --      % use point1.center instead
            ++(right:2) to [C, l=$C$]
            ++(down:2) --
            (point2.center) node[circ]{}         % use point2.center instead
        ;
    \end{circuitikz}

    \begin{circuitikz}[european,scale=1]
        \draw
            (0,0) node[ocirc]{} --
            ++(right:1) node(point1){} to [R, l=$R$]
            ++(down:2)  node(point2){} --
            ++(left:1) node[ocirc]{}
           (1,0) node[circ]{} --                 % explicit coordinate
            ++(right:2) to [C, l=$C$]
            ++(down:2) --
           (1,-2) node[circ]{}                   % explicit coordinate
        ;
    \end{circuitikz}

    \begin{circuitikz}[european,scale=1]
        \draw
            (0,0) node[ocirc]{} --
            ++(right:1)  coordinate(point1){} to [R, l=$R$]  % use coordinate instead
            ++(down:2)   coordinate(point2){} --             % use coordinate instead
            ++(left:1) node[ocirc]{}
            (node cs:name=point1) node[circ]{} --
            ++(right:2) to [C, l=$C$]
            ++(down:2)--
            (node cs:name=point2) node[circ]{}{}
        ;
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```